# How to get float* from Tensor<float> on Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime?

Tags: c#, onnx, onnxruntime, yolov7

I'm using nuget package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime to inference yolov7 model, use c# .net framework 4.8

After session.run, I have a Tnesor<float> as result, then I need to do some postprocessing,
iterate over the Tnesor<float>,but getting elements through [] is too slow,I have 1,867,320 floats need to traverse, it takes almost 300ms(i7 10700 cpu).I think it's because of its get/set methods.Can I just get the float* of Tensor's Buffer then use unsafe code blocks to speed up?

code like:

```
IDisposableReadOnlyCollection<DisposableNamedOnnxValue> output = Session.Run(input);
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
foreach (DisposableNamedOnnxValue res in output)
{
    sw.Start();
    Tensor<float> f_data = res.AsTensor<float>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 143640; i++) // output dimension：{1,143640,13} 
         for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
               float a = f_data[0, i, j]; 
    sw.Stop(); // cost 300-310ms
}
```

in c++,it only cost 3ms:

```
void PostProcess(vector<Value>& ort_outputs) {
    const float* pdata = ort_outputs[0].GetTensorMutableData<float>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 143640 * 13; i++) {
        float v = pdata[i];
    } // cost 2-4ms
}
```

I think the main reason is the performance loss caused by the unboxing of the get/set method of Tensor,I want to know if there is a way to bypass Tensor[] and get its internal Buffer?

Comment: A float is 4 bytes so you want to read 4MBytes. about 75usec a byte.  Where is data coming from?

Comment: just from memory,but its too slow, the same operation is 10000% faster in C++

Comment: C# is managed to prevent blue screen exceptions.  There is a lot of overhead to prevent these exceptions.  There isn't much you can do to run at same speed as c++ and make your code safe.  If you want the increase speed then run a c++ application, not a c# application.